# Javascript won't compile on IE but will work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm writing a search function using Javascript, which is nearly finished and works fine on chrome, but not in explorer. I've used the explorer developer tool and it tells me this is the line it can't handle:

```
if (compareElement.indexOf(compareString)!== -1 &&
    processFindings.indexOf(processes[i]) === -1)
```

the error is Object doesn't support this property or method.

the line used to read:

```
if(compareElement.indexOf(compareString)!== -1)
```

and it worked fine, it was only when I added the extra condition that explorer couldn't deal with it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi Ryan, IE doesn't seem to think that `processFindings` is a string. Are you sure it is one?

Comment: I think IE is the most brutal sometimes for JS. just cuz it works in other browsers doesn't mean there isn't a  js error. I think @zetlen is right in double checking your types and making sure they are strings

Comment: **processFindings** is an array, I thought there was indexOf for arrays?

Comment: `String.prototype.indexOf` was part of ECMA-262 ed 3. `Array.prototype.indexOf` was introduced in ECMA-262 ed 5 (ES5) so older browsers (from all vendors) don't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all versions of IE have an .`indexOf()` method for arrays.  There is a polyfill for it that works well though.

See here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

This may cause problems with code that does not iterate arrays properly however.

Comment: Some folks iterate through arrays using .forEach or using a for in loop.  The added `.indexOf()` shows up as a property and gets processed.

Anyone does normal a normal loop over the numeric indexes (which is the only proper way) is fine.

Comment: `.forEach()` only does the numeric indexes doesn't it? (Though it only does the numeric indexes that have actually been assigned a value, so for `var a = []; a[5] = true;` using `.forEach()` would skip indexes 0 through 4.)

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate the method (if it's not there) but using a prototype will require it to exist before any calls to it. An example:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement,fromIndex) {
        fromIndex = parseInt(fromIndex || 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] == searchElement) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```